# Contivo cli/utility commands

Tags: contivo

Is there some sort of cli command / utility that I can use to change some of the metadata inside of a Contivo xbm file? We are trying to set up an automated deploy to a second dev branch, but the prefix on the maps changes from branch to branch. I.E.  ABBranch: ABMap.xbm -> CDBranch: CDMap.xbm.

Also, as a second portion to this, is there a command that will also generate an Excel Mapping Correlation Report?